# bind variables for Oracle ADODB SQL statements

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, bind, adodb

I've tried unsuccessfully to find a really simple example.  I'm close but something is still wrong.  I want to use bind variables in a VB program I'm writing.  I keep getting missing oracle expression if I use @ for my bind variables.  If I use & for them, I get not all variables are bound

```
Dim cnt As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter

Dim test As String
Dim plcynbr As String


Dim sSQL As String
Dim lngLenName As String

lngsize = 50
lngLenName = "'bozo test'"

sSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET ID_Name = @theName WHERE ID = @id"

        dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=P1ltcent;User ID=userid;Password=password"
        cnt.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
        cnt.Open dbConnectStr



Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnt
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sSQL
    Set par = .CreateParameter("@theName", adVarChar, adParamInput, lngsize, lngLenName)
    .Parameters.Append par
    Set par = .CreateParameter("@id", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1)
    .Parameters.Append par


 For Each prm In .Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name & " : " & prm.Value
Next

Debug.Print cmd.CommandText


    .Execute , , adCmdText And adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```

So I displayed my parameters and they look good to me
&theName : 'bozo test'
&id : 1

I displayed my SQL and it looks good to me

UPDATE MyTable SET ID_Name = &theName WHERE ID = &id

but I'm still getting not all variables bound

Comment: Try `?` or`:theName` instead of `@theName`. Parameter must be without i.e. `Set par = .CreateParameter("theName", adVarChar, adParamInput, lngsize, lngLenName)`

Comment: Write `lngLenName = "bozo test"` instead of `lngLenName = "'bozo test'"` -  that is the purpose of bind variables, you don't have to quote or escape the values.

Answer (score 2):

Bind variables in oracle are usually prefaced with :

```
:my-bind-var
```

Look here for a similar discussion:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681536-RESOLVED-bind-variables-against-Oracle-%28ADODB-ORACLE-BIND-PARAMETER-QUERY%29

Effectively, you need something like this in your code

```
sSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET ID_Name = :theName WHERE ID = :id"
```

... then bind them (without the colon) ...

```
Set par = .CreateParameter("theName", adVarChar, adParamInput, lngsize, lngLenName)
```

Comment: still get not all variables are found when i use the : instead

Comment: actually I had to ONLY put ? where i want the variables.  I can't use names like &id etc.  And then in the bind variables you have to call them by the right names param1, param2, etc.   Once I changed those few things, it worked like a champ.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use `:variable` or `?` notation for SQL bind vars in VB6 ADO, but what really is important is to get the order right when adding the parameters to the parameter collection of the command object. The name of the parameter seems useless unfortunately.

Comment: I too continue to get the `Not all variables bound` error messages when using `:` bind notation. My guess is it has something to do with the oracle driver I'm using? (OraClient11g)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dim cnt As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
 Dim par As ADODB.Parameter

Dim test As String
 Dim plcynbr As String


 Dim sSQL As String
 Dim lngLenName As String

 lngsize = 50
 lngLenName = "bozo test"

sSQL = "UPDATE MyTable SET ID_Name = ? WHERE ID = ?"

    dbConnectStr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=P1ltcent;User ID=userid;Password=password"
    cnt.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr
    cnt.Open dbConnectStr



Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = cnt
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sSQL

   Set par = .CreateParameter("param1", adChar, adParamInput, lngsize, lngLenName)
  .Parameters.Append par


Set par = .CreateParameter("param2", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1)
.Parameters.Append par



For Each prm In .Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name & " : " & prm.Value
Next

Debug.Print cmd.CommandText


.Execute , , adCmdText And adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```